# deserialize a Json using a Response

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-core, xamarin, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a response delivered by an API in my Xamarin application as follows:

```
 public async Task<Response> RegisterUserAsync(string urlBase, string servicePrefix, string controller, UserRequest userRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                string request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userRequest);
                StringContent content = new StringContent(request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri(urlBase)
                };

                string url = $"{servicePrefix}{controller}";
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                string answer = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Response obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(answer);
                return obj;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new Response
                {
                    IsSuccess = false,
                    Message = ex.Message
                };
            }
        }
```

The problem is that although the response returns a status 200

[image: response]

I can't deserialize the response and cast it to a Response object (always returns false)

[image: anwser]

The API response is the following Json: (answer)

```
{
"firstName":"From",
"lastName":"Manecusei",
"address":"Planeta rojo",
"imageId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"imageName":null,
"imageFullPath":"https://martina.blob.core.windows.net/users/noimage.png",
"userType":"Cuidado",
"userTypeId":"35011633-db43-4d99-b0d2-1469471a7054",
"userStatusId":1,
"userStatus":"Registrado",
"fullName":"From Manecusei",
"usersQualifications":0,
"qualification":0,
"id":"0ca72f53-7932-4cb9-af37-13878b35f66a",
"userName":"froummahegafreu-4693@yopmail.com",
"normalizedUserName":"FROUMMAHEGAFREU-4693@YOPMAIL.COM",
"email":"froummahegafreu-4693@yopmail.com",
"normalizedEmail":"FROUMMAHEGAFREU-4693@YOPMAIL.COM",
"emailConfirmed":false,
"passwordHash":"AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAENxrPVzuqyuyAQOI52GGQK4K1R3KrMd/7ZJQlqkWPBaq1PG3X/ueOtFc0LpnkwXyvA==",
"securityStamp":"Y6EJJUXEN5UTXSUSBOMGBFPDC36VSNFM",
"concurrencyStamp":"44ce0b88-b8f0-4861-804f-52acc29097d6",
"phoneNumber":"88888888",
"phoneNumberConfirmed":false,
"twoFactorEnabled":false,
"lockoutEnd":null,
"lockoutEnabled":true,
"accessFailedCount":0
}
```

My Response.cs class is as follows:

```
public class Response
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public object Result { get; set; }
}
```

My User.cs class is as follows:

```
 public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        [Display(Name = "Nombres")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} no puede tener más de {1} carácteres.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} es obligatorio.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Apellidos")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} no puede tener más de {1} carácteres.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} es obligatorio.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Dirección")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} no puede tener más de {1} carácteres.")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Foto")]
        public Guid ImageId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nombre foto")]
        public string ImageName { get; set; }

        // TODO: Fix the images path
        [Display(Name = "Foto")]
        public string ImageFullPath => ImageId == Guid.Empty
          ? $"https://martina.blob.core.windows.net/users/noimage.png"
           : $"https://martina.blob.core.windows.net/users/{ImageId}";
        
        [Display(Name = "Tipo de usuario")]
        public string UserType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Id tipo usuario")]
        public string UserTypeId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Id estado de usuario")]
        public int UserStatusId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Estado de usuario")]
        public string UserStatus { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Usuario")]
        public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";

        [JsonIgnore]
        public ICollection<UserDisease> UsersDiseases { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public ICollection<History> HistoryUsersStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public ICollection<Qualification> Qualifications { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Calificación usuario")]
        public int UsersQualifications => Qualifications == null ? 0 : Qualifications.Count;

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
        public float Qualification => Qualifications == null || Qualifications.Count == 0 ? 0 : Qualifications.Average(q => q.Score);

    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I deserialize the anwser to an object of type Response?
Any help for me?

Comment: `answer` should be the json payload of the response, not the entire HttpResponse object.  Use VS or json2csharp.com to build a C# model for the json, and deserialize into that class.

Comment: Casting the Json element to a class that gives me JsonToCSharp there are no problems...Isn't it possible to cast this response to the Response class? @Jason

Comment: Look at the json contained in `answer`.  Look at your `Response` class.  Do they bear any resemblance to each other?  `response.Content` contains **only** the json content of the response.  Look at the actual `HttpResponse` object if you want metadata about the response itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this response class

```
Response response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(answer);
```

class

```
public class Response
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string imageId { get; set; }
        public object imageName { get; set; }
        public string imageFullPath { get; set; }
        public string userType { get; set; }
        public string userTypeId { get; set; }
        public int userStatusId { get; set; }
        public string userStatus { get; set; }
        public string fullName { get; set; }
        public int usersQualifications { get; set; }
        public int qualification { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string normalizedUserName { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string normalizedEmail { get; set; }
        public bool emailConfirmed { get; set; }
        public string passwordHash { get; set; }
        public string securityStamp { get; set; }
        public string concurrencyStamp { get; set; }
        public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
        public bool phoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
        public bool twoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
        public object lockoutEnd { get; set; }
        public bool lockoutEnabled { get; set; }
        public int accessFailedCount { get; set; }
    }
```